# Centered element in flexbox won't stretch till max width

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I have an element that is centered in a flex box, stretch up to it's `max-width` ?

In [this example](https://codepen.io/leoparis/pen/qMzPox), I want the red box to stretch up to 400px;

How can I make this happen ?

Comment: Use width: 400px; instead of max-width

Comment: Post your code in the question itself. This question becomes useless if your link reference breaks.

Answer (score 3):

To make it work I added `width:100%` on top of `maw-width:400px`

Answer (score 0):

Just use flex

```
.my-box {
 background: red;
 height: 100px;
 flex: 0 400px;
}
```

and

```
flex-direction: row;
```